# How to toggle data when access with url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, toggle

How can I toggle when I add `#ID` at the end of the URL? For example when I access a URL like `domain.com/xxxxxx#01` then my div will show.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toogle_button_<?php echo $link_shs['no_e'] ?>").click(function() {
    $("#<?php echo $link_shs['no_e'] ?>").slideToggle();
  });
  if (location.hash) {
    var id = location.hash.slice(1);
    var elementToShow = $("#" + id);
    if (elementToShow.length) {
      elementToShow.slideToggle();
    }
  }
});
```

`#01` is the id from `$link_shs['no_e']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `location.hash` to read the fragment from the URL, then use it to select the element. Try this:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
  $(window.location.hash).slideToggle();
}
```

You'd obviously need to make this more secure and check that the `hash` is a valid value that you want to allow, but that's the general pattern to use.

Comment: i edit my code, please take a look, it show and hide 3 times and hide it at the end.

Comment: You don't need the `slice()` call at all. You remove the leading `#` just to put it back again. Also, nothing about the code you've shown will execute three times. That is incredibly odd behaviour, as it should only run on load which can happen once per page. Can you set up a demo of the issue in a http://jsfiddle.net?